# terraform : provision resources on multiple clusters

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm provisioning multiple k8s clusters using terraform.
On each cluster, I want to create namespaces.

My first attempt didn't work, the resources stayed in status "still creating" forever.

Then I tried  to create multiple kubernetes providers.
I'm now facing a problem because they don't have the "count" field.

Indeed I'm creating conditional rules for deciding when to create (or not clusters).

See the logic below:

cluster_europe.tf

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8sProjectNE" {
count               = "${var.DeployK8sProjectEU == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
name                = var.clustername_ne
location            = local.rg.location
resource_group_name = local.rg.name
dns_prefix          = var.clustername_ne
```

clusterusa.tf

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8sProjectUSA" {
count               = "${var.DeployK8sProjectUSA == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
name                = var.clustername_usa
location            = local.rg.location
resource_group_name = local.rg.name
dns_prefix          = var.clustername_usa
```

The problem happened when creating namespaces.

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "NE-staging" {
count      = "${var.DeployK8sProjectEU == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
metadata { 
  labels = {
    mylabel = "staging"
  }
name = "staging"
}
depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE]
provider = kubernetes.k8sProjectEU
}


resource "kubernetes_namespace" "USA-staging" {
count      = "${var.DeployK8sProjectUSA == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
metadata { 
  labels = {
    mylabel = "staging"
  }
name = "staging"
}
depends_on = [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectUSA]  
provider = kubernetes.k8sProjectUSA
}
```

I define 2 kubernetes providers in main.tf and set provider = kubernetes.xxx in the resources that I want to create.

main.tf

```
provider "kubernetes" {
#count = "${var.DeployK8sProjectUSA == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
host = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectUSA[0].kube_admin_config.0.host
username = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectUSA[0].kube_admin_config.0.username
password = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectUSA[0].kube_admin_config.0.password
client_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectUSA[0].kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)}"
client_key = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectUSA[0].kube_admin_config.0.client_key)}"
cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectUSA[0].kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
alias = "k8sProjectUSA"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
#count = "${var.DeployK8sProjectEU == "true" ? 1 : 0}"
host = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.host
username = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.username
password = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.password
client_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)}"
client_key = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.client_key)}"
cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
alias = "k8sProjectEU"
}
```

Problem:

The kubernetes provider does not support the count field and it breaks my conditional creation rule.

```
Error: Invalid index
```

│
│   on main.tf line 32, in provider "kubernetes":
│   32:   host = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.host
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE is empty tuple
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the collection has no elements.
╵

[image]

I'm close to a solution, but it is failing at this final step.

Above was an attempt to find a solution, but the real need is the following:

I want to conditionnally create clusters ( Infra in USA and/or Infra in Europe and / or DRP infra). This is the reason why we need conditional rules.

Then, on each created clusters we have to be able to create resource (namespace is an example but we also have secrets, etc...).

If I don't define multiple providers, it is not able to connect to the right clusters and generate this kind of error:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say it does not support, rather that k8sProjectNE cluster wasn't created, hence there are no indices and it's an empty tuple as the error says. From what I understand looking at the code, that further means that `DeployK8sProjectEU` is not set to `true`. Also, make sure to understand the variable types as `"true"` is a string not a boolean. So you could try changing the condition to `var.DeployK8sProjectEU ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: initially we deploy our infra in USA only and not in europe (DeployK8sProjectEU set to false).
Therefore we don't want the kubernetes provider whose alias is k8sProjectEU. But since it does not have the count parameter, it is trying to evaluate k8sProjectNE[0] and obviously fail because k8sProjectNE does not exist.

Comment: said differently, we have 3 cluster, let's name them Common, USA, Europe.
We deploy Common and USA ( deployEurope = false) and we want 2 namespaces dev and staging to be created on common and USA.
This was we are not managing to achieve.

Comment: All the options for the kubernetes provider seem optional, so why not try something like `host = try(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.hosttry, null)`?

Comment: will try and let you know. thanks

Comment: that was the solution, it works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Implemented a solution like this:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host = try(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.host,"")
  username = try(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.username,"")
  password = try(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.password,"")
  client_certificate = try("${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)}","")
  client_key = try("${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.client_key)}","")
  cluster_ca_certificate = try("${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8sProjectNE[0].kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}","")
  alias = "k8sProjectEU"
}
```